# Add a query parameter using Javascript for a lot of links?

Tags: jquery

I've got a page full of links. I'm trying to add a querystring on the end of every one, so that:

http://www.example.com?x=1&y=2 becomes http://www.example.com?x=1&y=2&z=3

I want to parse every link and add this. I can't seem to find an elegant way of doing it using jQuery- any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
$('a').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('href',$(this).prop('href') + '&z=3');
})
```

loop each `a` element and add `z=3` to the end of the `href` property

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
$("a").attr('href', function(c, b) {
     return b + "&z=3";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href^="http://www.example.com"]').prop('href', function(i, href){
   return href + '&z=3';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
$('a').each(function(){
  this = $this;
  curr_url = this.attr('href');
  this.attr('href', 'curr_url' + '&z=3');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check this.attr('href').indexOf('?') > -1 before just adding a key/value pair. If there's no '?' you'll need to add that too.

You're probably best off using the native href API in javascript to parse the URL then add the bits you require to the part of the URL you require modified.

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/

You should probably also consider doing this using an "on" event trigger (jQuery latest). Augmenting the DOM is slow when done to a lot of elements, and will delay page display if added in the onLoad hook.

```
$('body').on('click','a',function(e){
    // Prevent it jumping straight out
    e.preventDefault;
    // Define vars
    var href = this.href,
        qstr = 'a=b&bar=foo';
    // check for structure of url and add query string
    this.href += ((href.indexOf('?') > -1) ? '&': '?') + qstr;
    // jump
    return true;
});
```